# Stripe AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects' (custom user model)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to configure Django Stripe Subscriptions.

And now trying to setup webhook to create a new customer data by below code.

**views.py**

```
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from subscriptions.models import StripeCustomer  

@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request)

...


#Get the user and create a new StripeCustomer
user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)

StripeCustomer.objects.create(
    user=user,
    stripeCustomerId=stripe_customer_id,
    stripeSubscriptionId=stripe_subscription_id,
)

print(user.username + ' just subscribed.')
```

Traceback and Error message is below.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/app_admin/venv_ruling/ruling/subscriptions/views.py", line 125,
> in stripe_webhook

> user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

I'm following this manual to create this app https://testdriven.io/blog/django-stripe-subscriptions/

The manual specify the code below.

**user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)**

but I'm using "custom user model". therefore I changed the above code to below

**user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)**

Below is other codes.

**My models.py**

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

```
class StripeCustomer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripeCustomerId = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripeSubscriptionId = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'CustomUser'
```

**My settings.py**

```
#used for django-allauth
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: This seems unrelated to stripe-python and a duplicate of your earlier question.

Comment: @Nolan H This code is part of stripe function of "webhook" and the content is slightly different from the earlier one. Earlier question did not get an answer but the new one got an appropriate answer because I modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` with `get_user_model()`

This line in your code is the cause of this error -

```
user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
```

`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` has a string type value.

Simply, replace it as shown below -

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model # import this in your module first.

user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
```

Comment: The problem was solved! Thank you very much!